Convergence and sequential compactness for nonlinear operators
I have a family of operators $T_n\colon X \to Y$ where $X,Y$ are Hilbert spaces. These operators are nonlinear.
What kind of notions of convergence does one have for such operators? I'm specifically interested in the case when the operators are uniformly bounded in some sense, e.g.,
$$\|T_n(x)\|_Y \leq C\|x\|_X$$
where $C$ is independent of $n$, and what kind of sequential compactness results there are. Can someone give more details or point out a reference? Everywhere I look is restricted to linear operators.

What else do you know about the operators?  In many applications, the "nonlinear" operators that arise still have some connection to the linear structure of the Hilbert spaces, perhaps by being "close to linear" in some sense.  If not, then the linear structure becomes irrelevant, and really all you have is some family of mappings between metric spaces.  There's very little to be said in that broad setting, beyond basic facts like Arzela-Ascoli.

Indeed the very word "operator", to me, connotes some sort of linearity property.  Otherwise I would just call it a "map".

Cross-posted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963692/limits-of-sequences-of-nonlinear-bounded-operators. And, as I noted there (and as Nate implied in the comments above), no such result is possible unless you specify more conditions on these nonlinear "operators". If we are just talking about arbitrary functions from $X$ to $Y$ under your sense of uniform boundedness (that does not even imply continuity!), the space is just isomorphic to the product of continuum many copies of unit intervals, which is not sequentially compact.

@NateEldredge I know they're Lipschitz continuous. That's about all I have..

@C_Al So the space of Lipschitz continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$? If you have a uniform bound on Lipschitz constant, and pointwise compactness in the range, then you do get a compact space under the topology of pointwise convergence. If the Hilbert space $X$ is separable, then it is sequentially compact. This is just Arzelà–Ascoli.

(Also a correction to my first comment: should have been the product of continuum many copies of the unit ball of $Y$, instead of the unit interval. And the number of copies, continuum, is under the assumption that $X$ is separable.)

@DavidGao Ok thank you
